# Performance of indexes that use nvarchar(MAX) vs ones based on nvarchar with fixed characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a string of certain amount of characters that I want to be an index of my SQL Server table.

Would it be possible to define it as `nvarchar(MAX)` or it is better to specify how many characters it could possibly have (such as `nvarchar(10)`), to speed up both writing and retrieving data using the index?

Comment: Only use `MAX` if you need to. An `nvarchar(MAX)` can store 2GB~ of data, which is about 1 Billion characters. If the length of your strings are going to be 10 characters or less, then yes, use an `nvarchar(10)`. Performance for query a `MAX` column is lower than one that is not, especially if you want to perform a `JOIN` or `WHERE` on them. Using an appropriate Length, Scale, Precision and data type are all just as important as each other.

Comment: You can't even create an index on varchar(max) as far as I know

Comment: An alternative would be to use FULL TEXT INDEX, but that should not improve your searches. On the other hand, you could define the text string variable with a maximum of 450 `nvarchar (450)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you *can* define an index on a `nvarchar` column that exceed the maximum length, but not on `nvarchar(max)`.

If you try on a column too large, you will get a warning like this:

> Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'idx_t_x' has maximum length of 8000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

So, inserts and upadtes will break if you have more than 900 or 1700 bytes in the record, depending on the version of SQL Server:

> SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL Database have increased the maximum size for index keys with nonclustered indexes. The new maximum key size for nonclustered indexes is 1700 bytes. The maximum key size for clustered indexes remains 900 bytes.

So, the effective answer is "no".  If you are storing text in the column, you might want a full text index.  If you want to prevent duplicates, you might consider various forms of hashing.

Comment: Even in SQL Server 2016+, you can't create an index on a `MAX` column. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9a825afbc451d7243a3e5e4f9303390)